# Parallel tasks don't work on Ubuntu 12.04 in VM Workstation

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, parallel-processing, ubuntu-12.04

Something weird is happening in my Virtual Machine which runs Ubuntu 12.04. The following script, that I successfully used before to run 7 tasks on 7 cores together, doesn't work properly anymore!

```
Prog out file1.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog1.log &
Prog out file2.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog2.log &
Prog out file3.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog3.log &
Prog out file4.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog4.log &
Prog out file5.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog5.log &
Prog out file6.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog6.log &
Prog out file7.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog7.log &
```

Prog is the executable name.

Previously (2 days ago), when I ran this script, each app executed on a single core and logging was OK.
Now, the apps don't start concurrently anymore. 2 or 3 cores start and then stop and only 1 continues running.

Could anyone please explain this behaviour?

System is an Ubuntu 12.04 on VM Workstation on Windows 7. No errors at all are shown in the log files.

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: Any error messages? Have you tried logging `stdout`? `Prog ... 2>Progerror.log` This isn't an issue with your script, it's an issue with the configuration of your virtual machine or the OS. You also don't say which VM you're running, the host OS or other details that might be useful. Most likely, this question is better suited for either the Ubuntu or Unix/Linux Stack Exchange sites. Flag your question and ask a moderator to move it.

Comment: There are no error messages what so ever. The system is apparently automatically queuing the tasks and running them sequentially rather than in parallel. I already have a log file, and no error at all is shown there. Thanks for the advice about the move, I'll do that if no one did that. Btw, I mentioned at the title it's VM Workstation. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: The logging shown in your script, if that's what you're referring to, only logs `stdout`. I'm sorry, in my earlier comment I meant "`stderr`" (and the example snippet is correct for that).

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. I'm gonna do that right now, the stderr thing.

Comment: I *do* think it's the system and not the script and not necessarily the program. However, it's sometimes good troubleshooting practice to eliminate the easy stuff. Checking `stderr` is one such item. Suggesting it was particularly prompted by your statement "Now, the apps don't start concurrently anymore. 2 or 3 cores start and then stop and only 1 continues running." though.

Comment: OK I did "Prog out file1.bin fids 72000 > logs/fitlog1.log 2> logs/errorlog1.log &" and the file errorlog was empty... any clue?

Comment: The program performes steps in each execution. I can see from "top" app and from the log files that the 2 or 3 run a little then hold, and only 1 copy continues...

Comment: Adding the 'vmware-workstation' tag to the question might bring in more eyes, but there are already 5 tags on the question.  Maybe drop the parallel-processing tag since the question is doesn't go into the algorithm of of Prog ?

Besides that maybe look at any changes on the Ubuntu or Windows machines, and any changes to Prog over the past 2 days.

Comment: Just in case it is some other terminal output (something reopened the terminal) blocking the background processes, could you try to "disown -a" them?

Answer (score 0):

Too vague description btw. There should be many possibilities of weird behavior, but in general, when you want to bind processes on Linux to specific CPU cores, start with following:

```
man cpuset
```

Otherwise kernel tries to do round-robin distribution of load and processes will 'travel' between cores during its run.